# How can I change the search separating symbol?

Tags: c#, winforms

For reference, this code comes from an answer to this question:

[Highlight a word or phrase with a color different from all the other selections in a RichTextBox text?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62012582/7444103)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

private class TextSearcher
{
    private BindingSource m_bsMatches = null;
    private RichTextBox m_Rtb = null;

    public TextSearcher(RichTextBox rtb) : this(rtb, Color.Yellow, Color.Red) { }
    public TextSearcher(RichTextBox rtb, Color selectionColor, Color currentColor)
    {
        this.m_Rtb = rtb;
        SelectionColor = selectionColor;
        CurrentColor = currentColor;
    }

    public string CurrentKeywords { get; private set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool CaseSensitive { get; set; } = true;
    public int CurrentIndex => m_bsMatches.Position;
    public Match CurrentMatch => (Match)m_bsMatches.Current;
    public MatchCollection Matches { get; private set; }
    public Color SelectionColor { get; set; }
    public Color CurrentColor { get; set; }

    public void GotoMatch(int position)
    {
        SelectText(false);
        this.m_bsMatches.Position = Math.Max(Math.Min(this.m_bsMatches.Count, position), 0);
        SelectText(true);
    }

    public void NextMatch()
    {
        SelectText(false);

        if (this.m_bsMatches != null && m_bsMatches.Position == this.m_bsMatches.Count - 1) 
        {
            this.m_bsMatches.MoveFirst();
        }
        else 
        {
            this.m_bsMatches.MoveNext(); 
        }

        SelectText(true);
    }

    public void PreviousMatch()
    {
        SelectText(false);

        if (this.m_bsMatches != null && this.m_bsMatches.Position > 0) 
        {
            this.m_bsMatches.MovePrevious();
        }
        else 
        {
            this.m_bsMatches.MoveLast(); 
        }

        SelectText(true);
    }

    public int Search(string keywords)
    {
        if (CurrentKeywords.Equals(keywords)) return Matches.Count;
        this.m_bsMatches?.Dispose();
        CurrentKeywords = keywords;

        var options = RegexOptions.Multiline |
                     (CaseSensitive ? RegexOptions.IgnoreCase : RegexOptions.None);
        Matches = Regex.Matches(this.m_Rtb.Text, keywords, options);

        if (Matches != null) 
        {
            this.m_Rtb.SelectAll();
            this.m_Rtb.SelectionColor = this.m_Rtb.ForeColor;
            this.m_Rtb.SelectionStart = 0;
            this.m_bsMatches = new BindingSource(Matches, null);
            SelectKeywords();
            return Matches.Count;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    private void SelectKeywords()
    {
        foreach (Match m in Matches) 
        {
            SelectText(false);
            NextMatch();
        }

        this.m_bsMatches.MoveFirst();
    }

    private void SelectText(bool current)
    {
        this.m_Rtb.Select(CurrentMatch.Index, CurrentMatch.Length);
        this.m_Rtb.SelectionColor = current ? CurrentColor : SelectionColor;
    }
}
```

Using :

```
numericUpDown1.Maximum = rbsearcherhl.Search(textBox1.Text);
```

For example the text in textBox1 is `"System"` but in my searching when you want to search for multiple words you add `,,` for example `System,,public` or `system,,public,,World`

but in the Search function in the TextSearcher calls to search for multiple words the using is with the symbol `|`

How can I change in the Searcher so the symbol will be like my `,,`    ?

[image: Example]

In the example to search for multiple words you type `System|using`
but instead I want to search for multiple words by typing `System,,using` or `System,,using,,public,,World`

Instead `|` how to use `,,`

Comment: You're going to need something like `Regex.Matches(MapMetacharacters(this.m_Rtb.Text), ...`; what goes in `MapMetacharacters` depends on how you want to search for strings like `|` or `,,`.

Comment: You should mention [where that code comes from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62012582/7444103), right?. The topic of this question is also described in notes there.

Comment: @Jimi You right sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the `System,,public` the user typed into your textbox1 (or whatever you called your textbox) and supply it to the TextSearcher as

```
Search(textbox1.Text.Replace("|", "\\|").Replace(",,", "|"))
```

Or however it is you make TextSearcher go

TextSearcher uses Regex syntax, the `|` in regex meaning "or" so "System|public" means "System or public". You want "System,,public" to mean the same so you either have to:

- teach Regex to use `,,` for OR instead of `|` or
- adjust your `,,` so it becomes what regex uses for OR (`|`)

Of the two I considered the latter to be easier! Also converted existing | to be escaped before replacing the ,,