# Why it's highlighting the text in richTextBox but only part of the keyword/s?

Tags: c#, winforms

It's not coloring the whole "Using" word in red in all places only the first one is colored in yellow but the rest it's coloring each time only the next part of the word.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Search_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            richTextBox1.Text = 
                File.ReadAllText(@"D:\test.cs");

            Highlighter lighter = new Highlighter(richTextBox1, Color.Red, Color.Yellow);
            lighter.Search("Using");
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The Highlighter class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Search_Test
{
    class Highlighter
    {
        private BindingSource m_bsMatches = null;
        private RichTextBox m_Rtb = null;

        public Highlighter(RichTextBox rtb) : this(rtb, Color.Yellow, Color.Red) { }
        public Highlighter(RichTextBox rtb, Color selectionColor, Color currentColor)
        {
            m_Rtb = rtb;
            SelectionColor = selectionColor;
            CurrentColor = currentColor;
        }

        public string CurrentKeywords { get; private set; } = string.Empty;
        public bool CaseSensitive { get; set; } = true;
        public int CurrentIndex => m_bsMatches.Position;
        public Match CurrentMatch => (Match)m_bsMatches.Current;
        public MatchCollection Matches { get; private set; }
        public Color SelectionColor { get; set; }
        public Color CurrentColor { get; set; }

        public void GotoMatch(int position)
        {
            SelectText(false);
            m_bsMatches.Position = Math.Max(Math.Min(m_bsMatches.Count, position), 0);
            SelectText(true);
        }
        public void NextMatch()
        {
            SelectText(false);
            if (m_bsMatches != null && m_bsMatches.Position == m_bsMatches.Count - 1)
            {
                m_bsMatches.MoveFirst();
            }
            else { m_bsMatches.MoveNext(); }
            SelectText(true);
        }

        public void PreviousMatch()
        {
            SelectText(false);
            if (m_bsMatches != null && m_bsMatches.Position > 0)
            {
                m_bsMatches.MovePrevious();
            }
            else { m_bsMatches.MoveLast(); }
            SelectText(true);
        }

        public int Search(string keywords)
        {
            if (CurrentKeywords.Equals(keywords)) return Matches.Count;
            m_bsMatches?.Dispose();
            CurrentKeywords = keywords;
            var options = RegexOptions.Multiline |
                         (CaseSensitive ? RegexOptions.IgnoreCase : RegexOptions.None);
            Matches = Regex.Matches(m_Rtb.Text, keywords, options);
            if (Matches != null)
            {
                m_Rtb.SelectAll();
                m_Rtb.SelectionColor = m_Rtb.ForeColor;
                m_Rtb.SelectionStart = 0;
                m_bsMatches = new BindingSource(Matches, null);
                SelectKeywords();
                return Matches.Count;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        private void SelectKeywords()
        {
            foreach (Match m in Matches)
            {
                SelectText(false);
                NextMatch();
            }
            m_bsMatches.MoveFirst();
        }
        private void SelectText(bool current)
        {
            m_Rtb.Select(CurrentMatch.Index, CurrentMatch.Length);
            m_Rtb.SelectionColor = current ? CurrentColor : SelectionColor;
        }
    }
}
```

but the result is :

[Only first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwADi.jpg)

It's coloring in red only parts of the Using key word and not all the word in all places why is that ?

Comment: Your code works for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/laUmi.png

Comment: Since [I wrote that code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62012582/7444103), I think I'm qualified to state that it works :) See the sample usage in the original question -- Double check that the Control you're passing to the Constructor is the right one an that the code you wrote that initializes the text selector is actually executed. Also note that the search is case sensitive by default, unless you set the `CaseSensitive` property to `false`.

Comment: @Jimi I updated my question edited it because it's working but not coloring the right way the word/s I also added an image to my question.  https://imgur.com/a/wU2AG5T

Comment: That's because you're loading a text file to set the `Text` property of your RTB in the Constructor of a Form, then immediately after perform the highlight => that won't work as expected: at this time, the RichTextBox handle is not yet created, so it has not yet replaced all `\r\n` occurences with with just `\n` (the line separator that this Control actually uses), so when the RichTextBox finally renders its content, the chars count is off by 1 per line. Use the `Load` or `Shown` events of your Form to perform the highlight. Anyway, only after the RTB creates its handle (or you make it do it).

Comment: As a general indication, use the Constructor of a Control (a Form, in this case), only to set properties and default states, never to perform actions. Most actions depend on the handle creation, so an action, triggered before the handle is created, may be deferred or never actually performed. -- Or, as in this case, performed too early, with unexpected results. -- You can force the handle creation, in case it's strictly needed. I don't think it's useful here.

Comment: Right thanks. using a button did the trick,