How do I make indicators different colors for different words?
I'm making a program which allows you to search for terms, and they'll all be colored in a respective color (i.e. you're searching for "wood" and "length", each occurance of wood will be colored in red and each occurance of length will be colored in blue. However, everytime I change the color of the indicator, even when changing the indicator's id, it changes the color of EVERY indicator. Why does that happen and how do I fix it?

You've probably just made a mistake in the way you're building up blocks of text in the RichTextBox, but there are many ways to do that. We'll need to see your code to spot it. Otherwise it's just a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926264/color-different-parts-of-a-richtextbox-string

I'll send the code when I'm home in about 30m

You might be better to delete the question and try again when you can include the code. Questions only stay on the front page for a few minutes, so almost no one will see your update.

Gotcha, thanks for the advice

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48358496/14171304 -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62012582/14171304
